Children's TV show about a group of kids who fight off flying pirates trying to steal a town's valuables
I'm trying to find a childhood show from about 2000-2010. Where a group of heroes (who I believe were kids) have to protect the people of a town from pirates in a flying ship trying to steal their valuables.
I watched it on Freeview. I remember the show being quite colourful and saturated and the people were 3D-animated.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Were there multiple episodes of this show or was it a TV movie?

Could this be Storm Hawks (2006)? A group of 3D animated kids join together to fight off aerial pirates.

Atmos. World of a thousand mountaintop kingdoms, each protected by a
Sky Knight against the forces of darkness: beasts, rogues, and worst
of all, Cyclonians. The greatest of all Sky Knights led the Storm
Hawks. His mission: unite the kingdoms and rid Atmos of evil forever.
But he was betrayed, the Storm Hawks defeated, and all hope lost...
Until now. I'm Aerrow, the last descendent of the original Storm
Hawks, and I've been given their mission. This is my squadron: Finn,
the marksman. Junko, the strongman. Piper, the specialist. Stork, the
helmsman. And of course, my copilot Radarr. We’re the Storm Hawks, and
for us the sky is never the limit.




